# jsf boolean checkbox with ui-repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a List of items that I would like to print on the webpage. For each item in the list I want to display a checkbox. When clicked on the checkbox the status of the item should be toggled.

`TodoItem` has a property `Status` that I want to update.

**Status**

```
public enum Status {
    Active,
    Completed,
    Archived
}
```

**Jsf Page**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{todoBean.selectedList.todoItems}" var="todoItem">
    <h:form id="todoItemStatus">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="filled-in" id="todo-item" value="#{todoItem.status}">
            <f:ajax listener="#{todoBean.toogleTodoItemStatus(todoItem)}" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

        <h:outputLabel for="todo-item" value="#{todoItem.title}" />
    </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

I have read that I cannot use `converter` in the `selectBooleanCheckbox`. When the checkbox is clicked, I want to update the `TodoItem.status` to either `completed` or `active`.

How can I achieve this without adding another list in the backing bean?

Comment: Why not add an additional 'setter' that does the 'conversion' for you? Might feel dirty, but since it is a simple workaround, I would not care to much

Comment: I think that won't work as the binding for value is 2 way. So the get won't work

Comment: Yes, you'd need a getter to and do the 'reverse' conversion in there... Or do I miss something?

Comment: I can't override the getter as will need the getter to return the enum value

Comment: Not overriding, adding a 'shadow' getter/setter. For clarity/readability I created an answer with pseudo code, not that it is **THE** answer but more than one line of code in comments is often not  clear anymore

Answer (score 1):

Why not add two additional methods:

```
public Boolean getBooleanStatus() {
    return status == Status.ACTIVE ? true : false; // But then what you really want
} 

public void setBooleanStatus(Boolean boolStatus) { 
    this.status = boolStatus == true ? Status.ACTIVE : Status.COMPLETED; // But then what you really want
}
```

And in the xhtml:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox class="filled-in" id="todo-item" value="#{todoItem.boolenStatus}">
```

But I do notice you have a 'tri-state' Status. Does that not cause a problem?